# Plotly Dash - Gradient Lines

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is it possible using Plotly Dash to create line graphs in which the line colors are gradient (purely for aesthetics)?

I tried using something like:

```
'line': {'color': 'linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 60%, white)' }
```

Example of entire graph code in plotly dash:

```
dcc.Graph(
    id='MORTGAGE_RATES',
    figure={
        'data': [
             { "x": MORTGAGE30US['date'],"y": MORTGAGE30US['value'],"mode": "lines","name": '30 YR', 'line': {'color': 'linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 60%, white)' }},
             { "x": MORTGAGE15US['date'],"y": MORTGAGE15US['value'],"mode": "lines","name": '15 YR',},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'MORTGAGE RATES',
            "paper_bgcolor": "rgb(46, 54, 65)",
            "plot_bgcolor": "rgb(46, 54, 65)",
            'font': {
                'color': "rgb(255,255,255)"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Do you mind to prodice a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular a sample of your data?

Comment: Then in order to understand better: are you looking for a colormap for your line?

Comment: I just wanted my graph's lines to go from one color to the other - for example blue to green (gradually). Not looking for a color map, this is purely for aesthetics.

Comment: so the color will depend on x rather than y?

Comment: yeah technically

Comment: Do you think that [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/streamline-plot-with-color-gradient/21207) could eventually help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is not yet available for 2D line plots, it is currently only available for 3D line plots, see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/581. It is however possible to use a colorscale in a 2D plot if you use markers instead of lines, see the example below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
x, y = t, np.cos(t)

data = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker={'color': x, 'colorscale': 'Rainbow', 'size': 10})

layout = dict(plot_bgcolor='white', margin=dict(t=0, b=0, r=0, l=0, pad=0),
              xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, mirror=True, linecolor='gray'),
              yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, mirror=True, linecolor='gray'))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Do you know how to get this into a Plotly Dash? When I copy and paste your code, it doesn't show up.

Comment: I would need to take a look at the full code of the app to find out why the figure is not rendering.

Comment: I figured it out, for those who have the same question in the future, you put the following in your dash app: dcc.Graph(figure=fig),

Comment: Any way to connect markers when you dont all the points in between - i'm just getting spaced gradient dots...

Comment: You can use `mode='markers+lines'` but as explained in my answer the line will not follow the colorscale, currently the colorscale can only be applied to the markers.

Comment: I also want the markers to be connected. Any update on this?